# net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver encountered communication error

Tags: java, snowflake-schema

Getting exception in
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
Using snowflake 3.6.27 library and java 11

net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: Failed to verify the signature..

Thanks,
Pradeep